# Magento2 : get image path of product

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, paths

I created custom page for getting products . I got all information  but how to get full image path. I am using getImage() it is showing image only how to get full path.

```
      <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().$_item->getUrlKey();?>" title="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getImage();?>" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: do you need image in what size? full, original size, thumbnail or it can be some medium size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the code below in your template file :

```
$imageBlock =  $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, 'category_page_grid');  /* $product pass product object here */
<a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $productImage->toHtml()  ?></a> asdasdfs
```

Comment: How do we know what the available options are for `$ImageType` in: `$imageBlock->getImage($product, $ImageType)`?

Comment: You can check all $ImageType in theme's etc/view.xml

Comment: This significantly slowed down my pages however is exactly what i want.

Comment: @SnehaPanchal, can we use $productImage = $this->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $_product->getImage(); like below

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to get the image URL without having to render the full image HTML code, and without calling multiple blocks, you can do this way :

```
$imageUrl = $product->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($product->getImage());
// Returns "https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/y/o/your_image.jpg"
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the image URL with

```
$image->getImageUrl();
```

or if you want to output it as  element:

```
echo $image->toHtml();
```

OR Try this :

```
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
$imageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```

> Note:  you need to create objectmanager if use last solution.

Comment: what i s $image here  @ Ronak

Comment: how to get $product

Comment: if you are using product page than whatever productObject you are using pass a single product here

Comment: Share your block code, so get proper solution

Answer (score 2):

One thing you need to keep in mind when getting a custom collection of products is how you filter the collection to have a values you need to be called on the front end. You say you have a custom page, so i will assume that you are creating a custom collection as well.

When you do you have to filter out what you will need. Inside you're block class, you will need something like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Namespace\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Custompage extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection() {       
        $attrId = $this->getAttrId();
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('name');
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('price');
        $collection->addFieldToSelect('small_image');

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Take note that we have `$collection->addFieldToSelect('small_image');` as a field to select from. If you don't do this, when you pass the call to `getImage()` the product object won't have the image url (and this is hard to see as the m2 objects are huge and hard to `var_dump`). So you would end up with a value of `NULL` coming back when you call for the image url.

Then in your template you can use:

```
<?php $productCollection = $block->getProductCollection(); ?>
<?php $imageBlock =  $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct'); ?>
<?php if (count($productCollection)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($productCollection as $product): ?>
        <?php $productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, 'category_page_grid'); ?>
        <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1"><?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?></a>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at how it achieved in magento at product/view page

> Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery

```
/**
 * Retrieve collection of gallery images
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getGalleryImages()
{
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    if ($images instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            /* @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject $image */
            $image->setData(
                'small_image_url',
                $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                    ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                    ->getUrl()
            );
            $image->setData(
                'medium_image_url',
                $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium_no_frame')
                    ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                    ->getUrl()
            );
            $image->setData(
                'large_image_url',
                $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large_no_frame')
                    ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                    ->getUrl()
            );
        }
    }

    return $images;
}
```

where `$_imageHelper` is:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
 */
protected $_imageHelper;
```